# How to download files with customer-supplied/managed encryption keys with Firebase Storage in Angular or Flutter?

Tags: angular, flutter, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

My app stores files with Firebase Storage. I want to encrypt these files conveniently on the server. Firebase Storage uses Google Cloud Storage. And Google Cloud Storage offers two options for this: [Customer-supplied encryption keys](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/encryption/customer-supplied-keys), where the app provides a key, and [customer-managed encryption keys](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/encryption/customer-managed-keys), where the app provides the name of the server-side “encryption service account” in Google cloud storage.

I think my Java back-end that **creates** my files would be fine: The [Firebase Admin SDK uses the Java Cloud Storage library](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/admin/start#google_cloud_storage_client_libraries). And there [Storage.BlobTargetOption](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-cloud-storage/latest/com/google/cloud/storage/Storage.BlobTargetOption.html#method.summary) has an `encryptionKey()` method for the customer-supplied encryption key, and a `kmsKeyName()` method for the customer-managed encryption keys.

But I don’t see how I can **download** files with customer-supplied/managed encryption keys in Angular or Flutter. In Flutter, getting a reference to a file [only lets me specify a path](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_storage/latest/firebase_storage/FirebaseStorage/ref.html), not a key or key name. And [getting a download URL for that reference](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_storage/latest/firebase_storage/Reference/getDownloadURL.html) has no parameters, so no key or key name here, either. The same is true for the Angular SDK: No way to specify a key or key name when creating the "bucket" to access a file (sorry, no link here) and [when getting the file's download URL](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/src/storage/ref.ts), either.

So: How do I download files with customer-supplied/managed encryption keys with Firebase Storage in Angular or Flutter?

Comment: Are you still having this issue?

Comment: @rsalinas Yes. See my own answer below.

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not possible, neither in Angular nor Flutter. As advised, I did submit two feature requests. But both linger and may not be implemented for a while, if ever.

- [FlutterFire discussion entry](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/discussions/4954)
- [Firebase JavaScript SDK issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/4443)